# Evento "keydown" no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo este evento "keydown" de JavaScript (para aceptar solo entradas numéricas), asociado a un input con su atributo `name = 'dni'`. El problema es que no funciona al intentar probarlo. Me parece el `return` tiene algo que ver, ya que el evento si captura la tecla que se va presionando.

Este es el código:

```
document.querySelector("[name='dni']").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

        let code = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        
        if (code == 8 || code == 13) {
          return true;
        } else if (code >= 48 && code <= 57) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    });
```

Saludos.

Comment: KeyCode está deprecado, más info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: el codigo se ve Buenardo , puede ser posible que el problema no sea el código, sino cómo estás probando el evento. Si estás ingresando texto en lugar de números, el evento no permitirá que se agregue el carácter y no se mostrará ningún resultado en la pantalla. Para probar el evento, asegúrate de que el input tenga el atributo type="text" o type="number", y que estés ingresando números en el campo de entrada. Si sigue sin funcionar, intenta agregar un console.log() en el bloque if-else para verificar si está entrando en el bloque correcto.

Comment: Hola Albert, al menos esta parte de tu código funciona bien (igual atiende la indicación de @Cris223511.dev,sobre el **deprecated**), tal vez el problema sea que estás intentando introducir los números con el teclado numérico, que tiene otros valores asociados ( 0=96, 1=97, 2=98, 3=99, 4=100, 5=101, 6=102, 7=103, 8=104, 9=105... si el mismo está activado).

Answer (score 1):

Retornar `true/false` funciona si a la propiedad `onkeydown` tiene un retorno, de esta manera:

```
onkeydown="return valid(event)
```

Ejemplo:

```js
function valid(e){
    let code = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (code == 8 || code == 13) {
      return true;
    } else if (code >= 48 && code <= 57) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input name="dni" onkeydown="return valid(event)">
```

Si usas `addEventlistener` tienes que usar [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
document.querySelector("[name='dni']").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    let code = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

    if (code == 8 || code == 13) {
      return true;
    } else if (code >= 48 && code <= 57) {
      return true;
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    
    //Este if tambien debería resultar, es lo abreviado de lo anterior
    //if (code != 8 && code != 13 && (code < 48 || code > 57)) {
    //  e.preventDefault();
    //}
});
```

```html
<input name="dni">
```